# How to get specific children of a xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am loading a xml document and I am having a foreach loop in its elements and I want to select child elements named `tag` in it.

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view>
    <tag>
      <name>content</name>
      <tag>
        <name>div</name>
      </tag>
    </tag>
</view>
```

And this is the code:

```
string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/xml/xml.xml"));
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
XElement xmlElement = doc.Element("view");
foreach (var tagItem in xmlElement.Descendants("tag"))
{
    //do something
}
```

The code written in foreach loop would contain all of tag elements in any depth, but I want to get the first depth ones(the children).

How to do this with linq?

Comment: If you have an xml just generate an xsd with xsd.exe and then generate classes (also with xsd.exe). You can then use an xmlserializer to serialize your xml to a your generated class structure instead.

Comment: Are the first depth `tag` elements always children of the `view` element? Then do what Ben says below...

Comment: If you just want the immediate children of `<view>`, then use `xmlElement.Elements("tag")` instead of `Descendants()`.

Comment: @BenRobinson Please put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the desired  elements are always children of the `<view>` element you can use:

```
XElement xmlElement = doc.Element("view");
foreach (var tagItem in xmlElement.Elements("tag"))
{
    //do something (only direct children)
}
```

There is nothing more to be done to get the desired elements. You can then however implement **your "do something"** with Linq, for example:

```
XElement firstElem = xmlElement.Elements("tag").OrderBy(e => e.Name).First();
```